# svmtrain function in matlab never exits ... do alternatives exist?

Tags: matlab, svm

I am trying to learn how to use support vector machines in matlab. I have the bioinformatics toolbox, which has SVM functions `svmtrain` and `svmclassify`.

I managed to successfully use it for some reference data sets, with some nice accuracy. When I try to use the svm on my actual data the training never stops. My data set is 400 instances in 25 dimensions, so it should not take very long?!

Can I use other solvers in matlab? I dont want to buy new toolbox please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that may cause problems for training, but it should not run infinitely. Do you get any errors when using the solver?

With regard to alternatives: [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) has an interface to [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab). This is a state-of-the-art library with thousands of users. I highly recommend it, because it is easy to install/use and offers additional functionality for parameter tuning and more.

Comment: I just installed the library you suggested and it works perfectly. Thank you!